# How to know 'sequence number' wiht getsockopt?

Tags: python, tcp, getsockopt

I'm listening my own binded socket on addr "127.0.0.0", and sending some traffic. Socket is SOCK_STREAM. 
May i get **sequence_number** and **acknowledgement_number** of incoming packet with **getsockopt**? If you now, please write arguments of this func. in python
Thank you:)

Comment: Please include your code in your post.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you already read the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockopt) and [Unix docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) on this function? The Python docs clearly explain that the arguments are just those defined by the Unix definition of `getsockopt()`, and we encourage askers to do their research before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm listening my own binded socket on addr  ... May i get sequence_number and acknowledgement_number of incoming packet with getsockopt?

You will not get information about sequence numbers from a plain TCP socket, i.e. one created by `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`.

Comment: Oh, i think u right... Once i knew original_dst and original_port of my stream sock using socketopt, i have decided it's possible...

Comment: @LevaDerbyshev: ip and port are static properties of the socket. sequence numbers are dynamic properties which change with each data you get and send. There are some dynamic information retrievable using [TCP_INFO](https://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html) but sequence numbers are not among these.

Comment: But i have been changed it using iptables, then all my packets have destination addr is "127.0.0.1"... Okay, i will know, thank u